# How do I use the target caption of a \hypertarget as the link caption in a \hyperlink?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

I'm building a software requirements document and using my own set of counters to generate unique requirement identifiers. I'm also grouping different requirements into longtables, e.g.

```
\begin{longtable}{l p{4in}}
F\FormatCntr{ModuleCntr}-\FormatCntr{ComponentCntr} & Some Requirements Category\stepcounter{RequirementCntr}\\
\hline
F\FormatCntr{ModuleCntr}-\FormatCntr{ComponentCntr}.\FormatCntr{RequirementCntr} & Specific software requirement
\end{longtable}
```

This will generate something like:

> F00-01 Some Requirements
>
> F00-01-01 Specific software requirement.

Now at some point later in the text, I want to cross-reference back to that specific requirement. I can use `\hypertarget` and `\hyperlink` and say something like "See this requirement" and have "this" link back to the referenced requirement but it would be much more elegant to say "See requirement F00-01-01" but "F00-01-01" must be linked automatically due to the dynamic nature of the counters.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the normal `\label`/`\ref` system. If a counter is increased via `\refstepcounter`, then an anchor is placed at this location and the counter appearance and the anchor name are made available for the next `\label`. Then `\ref`, `\pageref` can be used to reference the label. For free link texts `\hyperref` with the optional argument can be used:

```
\hyperref[<label name>]{<free link text>}
```

The counter value could also be used for an automatic label name, but then the label names in references do not get updated, if the counter value changes.

Comment: I think I can see how the normal label/ref system could be used for individual counters but I'm looking to automatically generate hyperlinked text that is composed of the values of multiple independent counters.

Comment: @user36792: `subsection` is an example of an counter that often comes with the values of other counters (`section`, `chapter`). The only important issue for `hyperref` is the uniqueness of the anchor names. Usually it makes use of `\the<counter>`, but prefers `\theH<counter>`, if it exists. Thus the latter macro can be provided to get uniqueness, if `\the<counter>` is not unique.